# Custom Grouped Table Cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, quartz-graphics

I am trying to draw my grouped table cells in the drawRect method.  I get the following results, but I have one problem with.  I want the outer border to be a darker, but I can not seem to accomplish this, which I am sure is a problem with my drawing.

I like the color of the line in the middle between the cells, just not the outer border of the cells.

Edit:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    const float kLineWidth = 3.0;

    UIColor *topLineColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIColor *bottomLineColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:225.0f/255.0f green:225.0f/255.0f blue:225.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:242.0f/255.0f green:242.0f/255.0f blue:242.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    CGColorRef bottomSeparatorColorRef = [bottomLineColor CGColor];
    CGColorRef topSeparatorColorRef = [topLineColor CGColor];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    UIRectCorner corners = 0;

    switch(self.position) {

        case OTCellBackgroundViewPositionTop:
            corners = UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight;
            break;

        case OTCellBackgroundViewPositionMiddle:
            break;

        case OTCellBackgroundViewPositionBottom:
            corners = UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    [backgroundColor setFill];
    [topLineColor setStroke];

    UIBezierPath *bezierPath =   [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f)];

    [bezierPath fill];
    [bezierPath stroke];
    [bezierPath setLineWidth:3.0f];

    if (self.position == OTCellBackgroundViewPositionTop) {
        // Draw the Bottom Line
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, bottomSeparatorColorRef);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, kLineWidth);
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapSquare);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0, rect.size.height);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);   
    }

    if (self.position == OTCellBackgroundViewPositionBottom) {
        // Draw the Top Line
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, topSeparatorColorRef);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, kLineWidth);
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapSquare);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0, 0.0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width, 0);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could get rid of a lot of that code if you used convenience's like `+[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:]`, then fill the bezier path, then stroke the bezier path. Then just stroke over the lines you want a different colour.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the top separator to white.

```
UIColor *topLineColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
CGColorRef topSeparatorColorRef = [topLineColor CGColor];
// Top Line
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, topSeparatorColorRef);
```

Simply set it to a darker color.

Comment: I tried that, but the top was being overwritten and still the same color.  I changed my code suggested by rmaddy, but now the sides are not being shown

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the code for the top position cell. First, you create a path that represents an outline of the whole cell. Next, you fill the background - good. Then you stroke the two sides and top - good. Then you stroke the bottom of the cell - good. Then you add and stroke the full outline path you created before doing the other parts - bad.

Get rid of the path you create and don't stroke that path. Your code for the background, top line, and bottom line are all you need.

The extra stroke you do last is redrawing the full cell outline in the last color you used which was for the bottom line. This is covering your top line stroke.

On a side note, you should use an `if-else` setup:

```
if (_position == OTCellBackgroundViewPositionTop) {
    // draw top cell
} else if (_position == OTCellBackgroundViewPositionMiddle) {
    // draw middle cell
} else if (_position == OTCellBackgroundViewPositionBottom) {
    // draw bottom cell
)
```

This sort of structure should always be used when you only need one possible path to execute. The structure you had is appropriate when it is possible or desired for multiple paths to be executed.

Comment: I removed the code which you suggested, but I still received undesired results.  The sides are no longer being drawn, see the edit

Comment: The path for your top line isn't correct. I didn't notice that the first time. You simply draw the one line across the top. You need a path that starts in the bottom left corner, goes up the side, around the corner, etc. ending in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Any guidance on how to draw that line, a link you recommend?

Comment: The code Paul.s posted should work well. You just need to draw the bottom line overtop the bezier path.

Comment: I am not getting the results I wanted, I'm sure i'm doing something incorrectly, I changed the edit, maybe you can give it a look?

Comment: You combined all of your code with the code given by Paul. You need to use just Paul's code. And replace the comment at the very end with the code that just draws the bottom line if it's the top position cell or the top line if it's the bottom position cell.

Comment: I did not catch that at the bottom, that seems very close.  I do not seem to be able to set the stroke width and color or the bezier path, am I doing something crazy here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking something like this might be more manageable. You'll have to tweak the bezierPath sizes etc to get the right.

```
UIRectCorner corners = 0;

switch(position) {
  case OTCellBackgroundViewPositionTop:
    corners = UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight;
    break;

  case OTCellBackgroundViewPositionMiddle:
    break;

  case OTCellBackgroundViewPositionBottom:
    corners = UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight;
    break;
}

[backgroundColor setFill];
[topLineColor setStroke];

UIBezierPath *bezierPath =   [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect
                                                   byRoundingCorners:corners 
                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.f, 3.f)];

[bezierPath fill];
[bezierPath stroke];

// Now stroke over the lines in a different colour.
```

## Edit

Looking at the code you have posted.

1. You have set the top line colour to white - hence it is white, maybe you meant to set it to the gray colour you require.
2. The outlines being drawn are being clipped. To solve this you could inset the rect by half the width of the lines you are drawing.

   ```
   rect = CGRectInsetRect(rect, 0.5f * kLineWidth, 0.5f * kLineWidth);
   ```
3. You need to set the stroke width before you stroke the line or it will use the default

   ```
   [bezierPath setLineWidth:kLineWidth];
   [bezierPath stroke];
   ```

Comment: I have never seen this method, do you have a link for sample code of this?  This looks like a cleaner method

Comment: What's wrong with the above? It shows an example and here are the docs for [bezierPathWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009276-CH1-SW14)

Comment: I'm not getting the results I wanted, specifically the white around the edges, I'm going for the look of the first image with darker borders, I edited the code if you wouldn't mind taking a look

Comment: I've updated my solution - I'm quite sure what the last bit of code is adding to the image - if you can explain that then I might be able to have another look.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'm just going to try to go back to my original solution, and i'll just post that when I get it to work